# Set label to textbox content

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

Here's what i want to do:

I want to be able to take the contents entered into a textbox.  Once the user hits the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key or the enter button I made, to have that content appear in a label I've placed on my form.

And have that same label change to whatever you enter in the textbox everytime you hit enter.

I hope I explained this good enough.  Thanks!

Comment: You create an event handler and do `myLabel.Text = myTextBox.Text` inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of TextBox and check if Enter is pressed

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a button to your form, double click it, inside the event add the code below

```
   label1.text=textbox1.text
```

and do some basic tutorials, dude

Comment: +1 for the correct answer so quickly.  -1 for the snark.

Comment: it's a not a snark really ;)

Comment: I'm taking a C# class in school but its not quite enough yet. But thanks for the reply. I had been trying to do something similar to this but I forgot exactly how it worked. So sorry :/

Comment: no need to be sorry fella, at all just trying to be cheeky and motivate you a little, most people on here just wanna help, we can have a moments tho, dont give up keep trying

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using winforms... First you need to enssure that your form will response to keyboard events.

So you need to set the property `KeyPreview` to true.
Then use the event [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write this code:

```
private void form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        myLabelName1.Text = myTextBoxName1.Text;
}
```